# Handle uploaded file with cgi c++ on apache2

Tags: c++, file-upload, apache2, cgi

Can we handle uploaded file from a html form with cgi c++ on apache2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could ;)  Requirements for your code is the same as for perl, etc: your cgi script (application in your case) should do correct output, should be able read data from stdin, etc...

You could check this as example http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialC++CGI.html